# Why this query throwing error while inserting record

Tags: mysql, pdo

i have created one table using following query

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
 `event_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `event_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `description` text,
 `event_date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `repeat` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 `share` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `share_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and now i am trying to insert record using this query

```
INSERT INTO events (username,event_name,description,event_date,repeat,share,share_type) VALUES ('bhavik','Will go home','','2012-11-11 18:10','0','','public');
```

error i am getting 
**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'username,event_name,description,event_date,repeat,share,share_type) VALUES ('bha' at line 1**

Comment: +1 for quoting an error message instead of just saying, "it doesn't work", like most people here do.

Comment: ok,i am using  PDO PHP i am giving current field name value and values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

repeat is a reserved keyword

use `repeat` in the insert statement

```
INSERT INTO events (username,event_name,description,event_date,`repeat`,share,share_type) VALUES ('bhavik','Will go home','','2012-11-11 18:10','0','','public');
```

Comment: awesome .. i changed repeat to event_repeat now it is working

Comment: @user1511547 if you have got your answer, you should accept it.